# Taylor series for $(1+z)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find Taylor series for $f(z)=(1+z)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ around $z=0$ with the main branch

$$f(z)=e^{\frac{1}{3}\log(1+z)}$$

I tried with taylor series for $e^z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$

and then $$e^{\frac{1}{3}\log(1+z)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\frac{1}{3}\log(z))^n}{n!}$$

but I got lost.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hint: $\log(1+z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-z)^k}{k}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem